# Inserting row with many columns of different datatypes into postgresql with psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

This question is about constructing an insertion SQL statement of a single record into a table that has many columns (135 in my case).

*Before anyone goes into analyzing why so many columns, let me simplify: I'm attempting to ingest raw data with the least modification possible, and the raw data has 135 columns.*

Now, following [this](https://stackabuse.com/working-with-postgresql-in-python/) guide,  a simple way to insert a record is this:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(<your db credentials>)
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT (ADMISSION,NAME,AGE,COURSE,DEPARTMENT) VALUES (3420, 'John', 18, 'Computer Science', 'ICT')");
```

Also note that if we're inserting a record without omitting any columns, then we don't need to specify the column names [more details here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (3420, 'John', 18, 'Computer Science', 'ICT')");
```

Should our data be kept in python variables, `psycopg2` allows us to do this:

```
admission = 3420
name = 'John'
age = 18
course = 'Computer Science'
department = 'ICT'
cur.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(admission, name, age, course, department))
```

But what is the recommended way of inserting a record with 135 attributes?
While my immediate intuition was to construct the SQL query myself, the docs do point out:

> Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

**So, to sum it up: how do I ingest raw data with an arbitrary number of columns into a table?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using [psycopg2.sql.Placeholder](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Placeholder) does the trick.

From the example:

```
>>> names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

>>> q1 = sql.SQL("insert into table ({}) values ({})").format(
...     sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, names)),
...     sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(names)))
>>> print(q1.as_string(conn))
insert into table ("foo", "bar", "baz") values (%s, %s, %s)

>>> q2 = sql.SQL("insert into table ({}) values ({})").format(
...     sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, names)),
...     sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Placeholder, names)))
>>> print(q2.as_string(conn))
insert into table ("foo", "bar", "baz") values (%(foo)s, %(bar)s, %(baz)s)
```

Therefore I guess I can do something like:

```
cols = ['ADMISSION', 'NAME', 'AGE', 'COURSE', 'DEPARTMENT']
row = [admission, name, age, course, department]
insertion_query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ({})").format(sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Placeholder() * len(cols)))

cur.execute(insertion_query, row)
```